# programming and running crystal on windows

Tags: crystal-lang

I need to work with crystal on windows. Does anyone know about an environment for windows?
And how to I run the files I wrote - if for example for now I'm writing in notepad?

thank you!

Answer (score 8):

In the wiki, there is a guide on working with Crystal on Windows: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/wiki/Porting-to-Windows

However, Windows support is very limited for now, but it's taken some steps lately.

The ongoing efforts for porting to Windows are tracked in https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/5430 As you can see, many basic features are still pending. Right now, you probably will not be able to compile any useful program on Windows.

But you can very easily develop on Windows in a Linux environment using Windows Subsystem for Linux. Instructions are in the docs: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/installation/on_bash_on_ubuntu_on_windows.html